# Java servlet app worked on my pc local but not working on my server development

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, centos

I already deploy my java servlet web app to my server . My web interface was shown but when I try to register/login from my webpage its thrown `HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error exception like below`

> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils
> com.mockup.Register.doPost(Register.java:38)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
> com.mockup.Register.doPost(Register.java:38)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

The description says that

> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
> fulfilling the request.

pom.xml

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>JSON.simple</name>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <description>A simple Java toolkit for JSON</description>
    <url>http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/</url>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>Yidong</id>
            <name>Yidong Fang</name>
            <roles>
                <role>architect</role>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+8</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://json-simple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://json-simple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</developerConnection>
        <url>http://json-simple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.6</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.2</source>
                  <target>1.2</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I installed tomcat 8.5 to my server which is using centos 8 OS . Everything worked fine in my computer local but when i deploy to my server it thrown this error . Sorry if i cant't deliver my message clearly but hope its help

Comment: It seems the installation of Tomcat is not correct. Did you try running a [sample application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the stacktrace is pretty self explanatory :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
```

When you deploy your application on your server, the application fails to load the above class. It might be because the version of the apache commons jar that is getting loaded is different in your server than in your local or you haven't provided the dependency. Please share your pom.xml for more analysis and also share entire stacktrace.

If you are using maven make sure you have it added in your pom like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: hi....just now i realise at my pc local i was using tomcat 8.0 but in my server i was using 8.5 . So the caused  like u said is version??

Comment: @wengweng Could you please share your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @wengweng make sure that the commons-codec jar is in the classpath for your application. In your local if you are having the scope as provided and have the jar in the tomcat then it will work.

Comment: sorry i still new on this but how do i access pom.xml never heard of it...

Comment: @wengweng are you using maven, ant or gradle as the build tool ? Check in your local tomcat if there is a jar for common-codec , if so add the same jar to the tomcat in your server as well.

Comment: @wengweng Do you have the commons-codec jar in your classpath in your local ? If yes follow the same steps and add it to the classpath on your server as well.